# how to make return type a LinearGradient or an AngularGradient in swift based on a condition?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, mobile-development

I have a function that currently returns LinearGradient as a background color. I would like to modify the return type such that the return type is either LinearGradient or AngularGradient based on a value of a variable?

This is the code I have:

```
func colors() -> LinearGradient {
   return LinearGradient(
            gradient: Gradient(colors: [
                Color(red: 135/255, green: 206/255, blue: 235/255),
                Color(red: 255/255, green: 160/255, blue: 122/255)
            ]),
            startPoint: .topLeading,
            endPoint: .top
        )
 }
```

Instead, I would like to do something like this:

```
enum BackgroundType {
   case linear
   case angular
}
```

then do the following: (the function is used inside .background() modifier)

```
func colors(backgroundColor: BackgroundType) -> ShapeStyle {
   if backgroundColor == .linear {
    return LinearGradient(
            gradient: Gradient(colors: [
                Color(red: 135/255, green: 206/255, blue: 235/255),
                Color(red: 255/255, green: 160/255, blue: 122/255)
            ]),
            startPoint: .topLeading,
            endPoint: .top
        )
   } else {
       return AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [
            Color(red: 135/255, green: 206/255, blue: 235/255),
            Color(red: 255/255, green: 160/255, blue: 122/255)
        ]),
                        center: .topLeading,
                        angle: .degrees(180 + 45))
 }
```

Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your `colors` function into a `ViewBuilder`.  Add `@ViewBuilder`, return `some View`, and remove the `return` statements.  Then this function will return the appropriate `View` based upon the `backgroundColor`:

```
@ViewBuilder
func colors(backgroundColor: BackgroundType) -> some View {
    if backgroundColor == .linear {
        LinearGradient(
            gradient: Gradient(colors: [
                Color(red: 135/255, green: 206/255, blue: 235/255),
                Color(red: 255/255, green: 160/255, blue: 122/255)
            ]),
            startPoint: .topLeading,
            endPoint: .top
        )
    } else {
        AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [
            Color(red: 135/255, green: 206/255, blue: 235/255),
            Color(red: 255/255, green: 160/255, blue: 122/255)
        ]),
                        center: .topLeading,
                        angle: .degrees(180 + 45))
    }
}
```